# Modifying behavior of Close(X) for Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form hosting a datagrid,from which a user can select which items they want to download. The form prompts the user to check if they want to close the form(when they click 'X') and if they do, any ongoing downloads will be aborted. I am handling this behavior with the method below :

```
Private Sub OnFormClose(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing

       If not MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to close this application?", "Close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
           <Code to stop the downloads>
        End If
    End Sub
```

I am trying to automatically close this form when the file that the user wants to download is downloaded completely. Currently the behavior is to have the user close the form manually. I am trying something like below :

```
Private Function downloadSelectedFile(string Address)

        Try
           fileReader = New WebClient()
           fileReader.DownloadFile(New Uri(Address), DestPath)
           Me.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            <Exception Handling>
        End Try

    End Function
```

Now when the code hits the `Me.Close()` line, it prompts the user if they want to close the form. This doesn't work because the user didn't really chose to close the form. Is there a way I can pass a parameter to the `Me.Close()` function to let it know this is a system triggered form closure?

Comment: Is the `downloadSelectedFile` method in the same form where the user picks files to download? Why would you choose to close the form after downloading one file? (not that it does this currently; you use DownloadAsync but don't await it so the form will close immediately; I wouldnt guarantee the task worker would complere the download in such a case)

Comment: Just add a private field of type Boolean, set it to True before calling Me.Close()  Now know what to do in OnFormClose().

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry I haven't written the representative code well :) there is an event which triggers when download completes and the method that handles that method will actually close the form. And yes that method is in he form. The reason why I would like to close the form is that once the file is downloaded, the user can further process it using my application and the window just sits there

Comment: @HansPassant short and simple. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this makes sense

- you ask the user if they're sure they want to quit and when they say yes, you cancel the quit.
- You never leverage download cancellation of an async by use of a cancellation token, and
- you close the form immediately after starting the download.

Perhaps you should have a child form that is dedicated to downloading a single file and reporting its progress. If your user ticks multiple files, open multiples of that form. Closing this download progress form will cancel the download but not kill the application (because it's a child form). The form can ask if the user is sure to cancel the download when it closes and if they say "no, not sure" then don't close the form. Additionally the FormClosingEventArgs that is passed to the FormClosing event (that the download profrsss form experiences) has a CloseReason that is one of the  [CloseReason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.closereason?view=netcore-3.1) enum values. You can use this to detect if the form's [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner?view=netcore-3.1) is closing, so if you set up the main form as the Owner of the progress form then the main form can ask "are you sure to quit?" and the owned progress bar forms can know they're closing because the owner is closing and NOT each ask "are you sure to cancel the download?" (That would get annoying if there are ten downloads in progress) so they can just cancel the download and close

It is perhaps common to have a tick box "quit app when all downloads complete" - the main form can attach to the FormClosed event of the progress form when it creates it/opens it. If the main form querirs the Application.OpenForms collection every time a child closes, and finds treat OpenForms only contains one form (the main form) and the "close when complete" is ticked then it can know to close itself with Application.Exit and it's own close reason will be different than if the user clicked the close button so it can know not to ask "are you sure to quit?"